# How to use the print step option in LTspice XVII?

Tags: ltspice, data, analysis, transient

I'm aware of the print_step option for transient analysis, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I'm using LTspice XVII for windows 10 to simulate a DC DC converter for about 3s (It is necessary to do it that long).

I use '.tran 100us 3s 0', so I would assume that only every 100us a data point is saved and when I convert to a .txt file I would get about 30000 data points per trace. But whatever I fill in for {Tprint}, nothing changes.

ALso when I change e.g. the stop time or the start time through the UI, the Tprint entry resets to 0, which is peculiar.

Comment: tstep: initial time step for numerical integration. This is just a suggested value as the simulator may reduce or increase this value as needed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you for the answer, but I'm talking about Tprint or print step, not time step.